# How do i get the likes fetched to the ui here..the like count is updated in the firebase but does not update in the ui. The code is shown below

Tags: flutter

The code below works and the like count  is updated in the database..but it does not show up on the ui. How can i get the like count in the specific place as shown in the code? In this code it does update to the database ..but it does not show the updated number in the ui. I also used setState in the function to update it to the ui but it still does not show the number which is there in the ui.

```
class Brew {
      final String id;
      final String name;
      final String sugars;
      final int strength;
      final int likeCount;

      Brew({this.id, this.name, this.sugars, this.strength, 
      this.likeCount});
      }


       class BrewData {
      final String id;
      final String name;
      final String sugars;
      final int strength;
      final int likeCount;

      BrewData({this.id, this.name, this.sugars, this.strength, 
      this.likeCount});


    factory BrewData.fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        return BrewData(
          id: doc.documentID,
          name: doc['name'],
          sugars: doc['sugars'],
          strength: doc['strength'],
          likeCount: doc['likeCount'],
        );
      }

    }






          class BrewTile extends StatefulWidget {
              final Brew brew;


              BrewTile({ this.brew});

              @override
              _BrewTileState createState() => _BrewTileState();
            }

            class _BrewTileState extends State<BrewTile> {
             int _likeCount = 0;
              bool _isLiked = false;

             @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                  child: Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 6.0, 20.0, 0.0),
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 25.0,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[brew.strength],
                        backgroundImage: 
                        AssetImage('assets/coffee_icon.png'),
                      ),
                      title: Text(brew.name),
                      subtitle: Text('Takes ${brew.sugars} sugar(s)'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                     Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              IconButton(
                                icon: _isLiked
                                    ? Icon(
                                        Icons.favorite,
                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                      )
                                    : Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                                iconSize: 30.0,
                                onPressed: () {
                                  if (_isLiked) {
                              _likeCount++;
                              _isLiked = false;
                              print(_likeCount);
                              DatabaseService()
                                  .updateLikes(id: widget.brew.id, value: 
           1);
                            } else {
                              print(true);
                              _likeCount--;
                              _isLiked = true;
                              DatabaseService()
                                  .updateLikes(id: widget.brew.id, value: 
          -1);
                              print(_likeCount);
                            }
                          });
                                },
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 
                                  12.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  '${_likeCount.toString()} likes',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                );
              }
            }



    List<Brew> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
        return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
          //print(doc.data);
          return Brew(
              id: doc.documentID ?? '',
              name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
              strength: doc.data['strength'] ?? 0,
              sugars: doc.data['sugars'] ?? '0',
              likeCount: doc.data['likeCount'] ?? 0,);
        }).toList();
      }


    Future<void> updateLikesCount({String id int value}) async {
        return await brewCollection
            .document(id)
            .updateData({'likeCount': FieldValue.increment(value)});
      }

     Future<void> updateBrewData(String sugars, String name, int strength, int likeCount) async {
        return await brewCollection.document(uid).setData({
          'sugars': sugars,
          'name': name,
          'strength': strength,
          'likeCount': likeCount,
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay this is a really easy fix in brew_tile.dart make this change

```
 bool _isLiked = false;
  int _likeCount;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _likeCount = widget.brew.likeCount;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(BrewTile oldWidget) {
    if (_likeCount != widget.brew.likeCount) {
      _likeCount = widget.brew.likeCount;
      print('initState: ${widget.brew.bio} ${widget.brew.likeCount}');
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }


Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                    child: Text(
                      '$_likeCount likes',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211986/discussion-on-answer-by-wcyankees424-how-do-i-get-the-likes-fetched-to-the-ui-he).

Comment: can you help with this please https://stackoverflow.com/q/61284780/12205087